# Django: get top tags?

Tags: python, django, sorting, tags

I'm using Django and the django-taggit app. For now, I pass the tags as they are:

```
def tags_page(request):
    """A page that displays all the tags."""
    tags = Tag.objects.all()
    response = render(request, 'tags_page.html', {'tags': tags})
    return response
```

In order to render a page with all of them. I'm not really sure how they are passed, but I want to put the top tags first, sort them according to the times they are used. But I'm not sure how to do that. Do I use order_by in some way? Thank you

Comment: Actually, I think I found it, let me check further...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, if, for example, the tags are applied to a model called Joke, you can simply do this:

```
tags = Joke.tags.most_common()
```

And it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the tags are stored in a list:

```
sorted(lst, key=lst.count, reverse=True)
```

`collections.Counter` also works and has the advantage of being `O(n)`

```
counts = collections.Counter(lst)
new_list = sorted(lst, key=lambda x: -counts[x])
```

Comment: I actually found a really simple answer.